# how to save belongstomany checkboxes in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a set of checkboxes with a belongs to many relationship. I couldnt use a multiple checkbox option for various reasons. The table Tutors has a belongsToMany relationship with subjects table. I get the correct checkboxes checked when it loads and when I update the checboxes I get the correct checkbox data returned but how do i save this? The docs say i need to put the id's in an array for the correct Subjects to be checked . I tried a few things but I couldnt save the data. I dont get an error, just not saving.

```
//view

          foreach ($subjects as $key => $item) {
              $sub=$item->name;
              $val=0;
              foreach ($tutor->subjects as $key2 => $item2) {
                  $sub2=$item2->name;
                  if ($sub==$sub2){
                        $val=1;
                       break;
                  }
              }

          echo $this->Form->hidden('subjects.'.$key.'.id', ['value'=>$item->id]);

                echo $this->Form->input('subjects.'.$key.'.checkedvalue', ['label'=>$sub,
                    'checked'=> $val,'type'=>'checkbox']);

           }

//controller
     public function edittest5($id = null)
    {
        $tutor = $this->Tutors->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['AvailabilityForTutors','Subjects']
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {

            $tutor = $this->Tutors->patchEntity($tutor, $this->request->data(),['associated' => ['AvailabilityForTutors','Subjects']] );
         //  $tutor->dirty('availability_for_tutors', true);
       debug($tutor);


            $this->Tutors->save($tutor,[
                       // 'atomic'=>false,
                        'validate' => false,
                        'associated' => ['Subjects']
                    ]); 


             return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edittest5',$id]);

        }

         $subjects = $this->Tutors->Subjects->find('all', ['limit' => 200]);
```

returned data

```
'first_name' => 'drew',
'subjects' => [
    (int) 0 => [
        'id' => '1',
        'checkedvalue' => '1'
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'checkedvalue' => '0'
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'checkedvalue' => '0'
    ],
    (int) 3 => [
        'checkedvalue' => '0'
    ],
    (int) 4 => [
        'id' => '5',
        'checkedvalue' => '1'
```

Comment: Please explain if: a) you want to know how to create a correct html input so that the data is ready to be saved, or b) you can't modify the way you create the html input so you want to know how to process the data so that it can be saved?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I want to create the checkbox display without multiple option as I have done this so far. So anyway that can get the data I created cab saved is what I want. I think that is option a)?

Comment: I still cant get a solution to this. Is there a tutorial that explains this better?